# How to uninstall old version of Sourcetree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I install  [Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) since v1.52 and update that from auto update. today I downloaded last version (2.0.1) from website and install it. 
When I open sourcetree see

[image: this error].

I try to find that folder but it not exist in Program file folder! or there is one application with name sourcetree in Add/Remove program.. Could any one help how I uninstall older version? Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Go into your Control Panel and the section for managing installed programs (they seem to rename it in every version of Windows). You should see some entries like below:

[image: Different SourceTree versions installed at the same time]

The version number is in the last column.

1. Select any old version one at a time
2. Right click on it
   [image]
3. Click **Uninstall** and follow the instructions
4. If you get a message like this:
   [image]
   just click Yes
5. Otherwise, you should see a message like this:
   [image]
6. Repeat until only the most recent version remains

Comment: I have only one sourcetree application in Add/Remove Application...i think finally i must remove sourcetree completely and then install again to solve this problem

Comment: note that the version of sourcetree in add/remove program is 2.0.19

Comment: @combo_ci You might have an incomplete uninstallation. Try installing exactly the same versions again, and then immediately uninstall them. With luck, it will clean up any registry entries or the like that are still hanging around.

Comment: its a bit difficult because i update sourcetree from autoupdate and must search for exact version that warn in open application...i have new think : may be could uninstall old sourcetree with use **/i** switch in sourcetree.exe in program file

Comment: Dannis: Do you have a link for download sourcetree 1.9.1?

Comment: @combo_ci Try http://downloads.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/windows/SourceTreeSetup_1.9.1.exe It's a direct link.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this exact same problem today, after installing SourceTree 2.0.20.1 in response to the [critical security update](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/sourcetree-security-advisory-2017-05-10-900820365.html) released yesterday.

The installer, and the new SourceTree executable too, actually, can see the old executables under `Program Files (x86)`, mine are under the Atlassian folder, too. The config files from previous versions are also under `(C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Atlassian)`. Or it could be looking at old registry keys.

The new SourceTree installs to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\SourceTree\app-2.0.20.1`, so I'm guessing deleting the old folders would be sufficient---there does not seem to be a straightforward way of uninstalling SourceTree cleanly, at least not from my Googling.

Or you can just ignore the warning. As the message says, future versions of the newer SourceTree would be easier to update, and shouldn't touch your old versions.

Comment: On my computer the old SourceTree is installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Atlassian\SourceTree`. The new sourceTree is installed in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\SourceTree\app-2.0.20.1`. You can check this by adding the `File version` column to your Windows Explorer view.

Comment: @CJ Dennis : i find to version on my computer by your guide .. do you have a way to remove old version in program file folder?(your answer in my question not work.. please suggest a new answer if you know)

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was an entry in my registry that prevented me from uninstalling the older version, so I installed it again, and uninstalled from the control panel. It worked!

Then I installed the new version, hope this helps